# reduce the size of executable visual studo 2017 community

Tags: c++

I am trying to reduce the size of my executable to ~20k , and I am copiling without symbols , debuing info. I also added runtime library /MD , but I after execute it on windows 7 , 8 or xp it says msvcp140-dll error visual c++ 
main.cpp

```
#include "class.h"
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32")
```

Comment: ***xp it says msvcp140-dll error*** That means you need to install the Visual Studio 2017  redistributable on these machines. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads yes this will be a 14+ MB download / install.

Answer (score 1):

If you want really small executables for simple tasks, you're going about it the wrong way.

1) Use no libc at all.

2) Use `RawEntryPoint` for your entry. It's prototype is

```
DWROD WINAPI RawEntryPoint()
```

3) Call all the Win32 functions in `kernel32.dll` for what you need.

If you find this too much of a headache, it's probably not worth it. You will spend three or four days working on this. Double-check your requirements. Usually, static linking is what you really want.